# MySQL column length limits - cut off long string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

When I tried to insert some text string into one column on MySQL table, I noticed there is a limit of 1000 character on that column, and anything over that limit being cut off.

I defined that column as `TEXT` type, and I cannot find anywhere to get rid of that limitation.

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description TEXT,
    other_stuff VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

The `description` column being set to maximum 1000 characters somewhere. I need to change it to 5000.

Do you know where to remove the MySQL table column length limitations?

Comment: Does the form input you're submitting from have a 1000 maxlength?

Comment: no, i am trying to insert from a php script, which read a text file, not a web form.

Comment: The max for varchar is 255 so adding 5000 does not do anything and limits till 65,535 bytes so u may need to use longtext or MEDIUMTEXT – up to 16 Mb, 3 bytes overhead

Comment: i am not using varchar, but "text" type, which should be 65535, right? however, where is that 1000 character limit from? i have no clue to find it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and believe it's because the TEXT field has a "precision" setting.  Trying to figure out how to change the precision of the field

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
create table x (
id int auto_increment,
description varchar(5000),
other_stuff varchar(50),
primary key(id)
)
```

Or to do it without recreating the table:

```
alter table x change description description varchar(5000);
```

Comment: i tried varchar(5000), still the same problem. is there anywhere mysql system level/php/linux can set that limit?

Comment: For what I know, the limit is not in MySql. I found a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456158/mysql-prepare-statement-maximum-length-1000-characters

Comment: that guy didn't say how to fix it? how my variable sqlString was limited is what i really want to know.

Comment: Well, he just declared a variable  sqlString varchar(1000) in his SQL script. But the point is I don't think the limitation is in MySQL. It must be somewhere else, in PHP or the DB connector/driver you're using.

Comment: gosh, you save my day. stupidity is everywhere! i found it out!

Comment: thank you, max. i was thinking system level. clearly i missed my mistake there.